# Android studio: how downgrade SDK to version 33.0.0?

Tags: react-native, android-studio, sdk

I am trying to setup my react-native project. I diagnose what needs to happen with the command 'npx react-native doctor'. I fixed all the problems so far, but I am stuck on this last one:

[image]

It seems I need to downgrade my SDK version. I've seen suggestion to do this in the SDK manager of Android studio, but I do not see Version 33 over there. How should I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I think your system only have sdk version 34.0.0 installed in you android sdk.

You need to install android 33.0.0 version which is default version come out of the box when we create our react native app according to current react native version.

So, the solution for this, install the sdk version 33.

Follow the below steps to install the 33.0.

1. Go to **Appearance & Behavior → System Settings → Android SDK**
2. Select the "**SDK Platforms**" tab from within the SDK Manager, then check the box next to "Show Package Details" in the bottom right corner. Look for and expand the Android 13 (Tiramisu) entry, **then make sure the following items are checked:**

   2.1 **Android SDK Platform 33**

   2.2 **Intel x86 Atom_64 System Image or Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image or (for Apple M1 Silicon) Google APIs ARM 64 v8a System Image**
3. select the "**SDK Tools**" tab and check the box next to "**Show Package Details**" here as well. Look for and expand the "Android SDK Build-Tools" entry, **then make sure that 33.0.0 is selected**
4. Finally, **click** "**Apply**" to download and install the Android SDK and related build tools.

[image: Android SDK platform 33]

[image: SDK Tools for 33]