# Trouble Configuring ANDROID_HOME and PATH Mac OS

Tags: android-studio, nativescript, nativescript-vue

ERROR:
No compatible version of the Android SDK Build-tools are installed on your system. You can install any version in the following range: '>=23 <=33'.

When I run echo $ANDROID_HOME    returns  /Users/lorling/Library/Android/sdk

In Android studio path says /Users/lorling/Library/Android/sdk

When I run echo $PATH return a real long path. End is /bin:/Users/lorling/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools

In Android studio Android sdk platforms: Android API 34 & Andriod 13 tiramisu are installed.

When I run  nano  `~/ .zshrc

```
export PATH="$HOME/.yarn/bin:$HOME/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:$PATH"

export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools


export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This load$


source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/chruby.sh
source /usr/local/opt/chruby/share/chruby/auto.sh
chruby ruby-3.1.3
```

Using node v v18.18.2

and npm v 10.2.1

Here is what Android Studio configuration looks like:

If I uninstall Android API 34 and keep Android 13 same results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround that a friend for me.

[Android studio: how downgrade SDK to version 33.0.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796654/android-studio-how-downgrade-sdk-to-version-33-0-0)

I think the key was adding 33.0 to Android 34 build tools